# How to write sql select query for following

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables

Table 1: **person**

```
columns: id,name,address,code
```

Table 2: **carDetails**

```
columns: id,person_id,car_brand
constraints: FL==>carDetails(person_id) reference person(id)
Note: carDetails is having multiple details for single person
```

Table 3: **mobileDetails**

```
columns: id,person_id,mobile_brand
constraints: FL==>mobileDetails(person_id) reference person(id)
Note: mobileDetails is having multiple details for single person
```

Similarly i have lot of details like car and mobile for person

What I want to select is:

```
person(id),
person(name),
Array of carDetails(brand) belonging to that particular person(id)
Array of mobileDetails(brand) belonging to that particular person(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write this query using subqueries for the aggregation:

```
select p.*, c.car_brands, m.mobile_brands
from person p left join
     (select c.person_id, array_agg(cd.car_brand) as car_brands
      from car_details c
      group by c.person_id
     ) c
     on c.person_id = p.id left join
     (select m.person_id, array_agg(m.mobile_brand) as mobile_brands
      from mobile_details m
      group by m.person_id
     ) m
     on m.person_id = m.id;
```

Two notes:

- You want to use `left join`, in case you have no data in one of the tables for some people.
- You want to aggregate *before* joining to avoid duplicates.  Although you could add `distinct` to `array_agg()` that incurs a performance penalty.

If you are filtering the people, it is often more efficient to do this using a subquery or (equivalently) as lateral join:

```
select p.*,
       (select array_agg(cd.car_brand) as car_brands
        from car_details c
        where c.person_id = p.id
       ) as car_brands,
       (select array_agg(m.mobile_brand) as mobile_brands
        from mobile_details m
        where m.person_id = p.id
       ) as mobile_brands
from person p;
```

Comment: do we have any other option other than subquery because i have almost 32 tables more, which contains various info related to single person, and writing subqueries for all those will be bulky

Comment: @BZT . . . The subqueries are your best bet.  With 32 tables, the number of combinations would get very large with just `join`s.